# UFT script - leading zero not retaining

Tags: leading-zero

I have a UFT script that is loosing the leading zero when running. The datatable is an excell spreadsheet and I have tried the leading apostrophe already and still loosing the leading zero. On some of the testing PC, the script work without any apostrophe but only my PC and some new configured PC that we are not able to run the script. Is there any configuration missing on my PC?

Thanks

- I have tried to add the leading apostrophe ex. '01 and when running the script, it enter 1 instead 01.

The script works on some pc without the leading apostrophe. Is there any missing setup while configurating my PC?

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Which script are you talking about? Please [help us help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)

Comment: We are using UFT One to make SAP scripting. The datatable is in Excell spreadsheet.